# Why can't I draw on my image's canvas?

Tags: image, delphi, canvas, delphi-xe8

I'm using Delphi XE8.

I'm loading a background image to my Image:

```
var
  Png: TPngImage;
begin
  Png := TPngImage.Create;
  try
    Png.LoadFromResourceName(HInstance, 'background');
    Image1.Picture.Graphic := Png;
  finally
    Png.Free;
  end;
```

This works alright, but when I try to draw on the image's canvas (I tried `LineTo`) I get this error:

> Can only modify an image if it contains a bitmap

How can I draw on an image which I have loaded a picture into?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The answer can be found in the error message that you quoted:

> Can only modify an image **if it contains a bitmap**.

So, create a bitmap object, assign the PNG image to that bitmap, and then assign that bitmap to the `TImage` control's `Picture`.

Comment: Or start using Graphics32 library (http://graphics32.org/wiki/) which does not have such limitation. Not to mention the fact that Graphics32 library supports hardware acceleration when drawing so it could come very useful if more complex drawing is required.

Comment: @SilverWarior I don't see where hardware acceleration comes into this.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan Hardware acceleration was mentioned as biggest advantage of Graphics32 library in comparison to VCL TImage component. Granted nothing in the question suggest that OP needs this. But knowing it is available it might provide OP with the ability to further expand his original idea.

Comment: @SilverWarior Blitting an HBITMAP onto the screen with GDI is already fast. Why do you think that graphics32 will do it better? Can you elaborate on what specific form of hardware acceleration will be used by graphics32 in this scenario?